# Questions about several Class Descriptions

Tags: c++, class, registry

when reading the following OpenFoam class descriptions I am not able to understand all of it:

1. Time: Class to control time during OpenFOAM simulations that is also
   the top-level objectRegistry.
2. Clock:Read access to the system clock with formatting.
3. CpuTime:Starts timing CPU usage and return elapsed time from start.
4. TimePaths: A class for addressing time paths without using the Time
   class.
5. objectRegistry: Registry of regIOobjects.
6. regIOobjects:regIOobject is an abstract class derived
   from IOobject to handle automatic object registration with
   the objectRegistry.
7. IOobject: IOobject defines the attributes of an object for which
   implicit objectRegistry management is supported, and provides the
   infrastructure for performing stream I/O.

Questions:

1. What means top-level objectRegistry?
2. what means with formatting?
3. Does "Starts timing CPU usage" mean the same as "Starts CPU usage"?
4. What is meant with "adressing time paths" and what is a "time path"
   in this context?
5. What is a ObjectRegistry class good for?
6. What is meant with "automatic object registration with the
   objectRegistry"?
7. What is meant with "objectRegistry management" ?

Hopefully some people with more programming knowledge will be able to teach me something here :) .

greetings
streight

Comment: "OpenFoam descriptions" : you mean the doc ? Either start with more basic programming tasks, or ask your questions in the [OpenFoam forum](http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam/).

Comment: @Synxis : Yes I mean the descriptions from the doc. Have posted the question now also in the OpenFoam forum.